# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - more threads than connection

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Several jobs get executed on a machine. For each job, I have to call an external service (plus do some other work). The number of times the external service has to be called for *a job* is not known beforehand, or even when the job starts as the job processing involves streaming input data.

Before starting the job, I have to create *certain number of threads* for processing - as part of the processing it calls the external service.

Say the service supports only 100 TPS (transactions per second) and maximum 10 jobs can run on a machine
and I do not want to bombard the service.

The problem is in deciding the number of worker threads to be allocated for *each job*. Since in the worst case 10 jobs could run at a time, I could allocate 10 threads for each job. But if only one job is running with 10 threads I would be under-utilizing the service.

I think I could use [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) for pooling the threads and use them to access the service. I could use a `DefaultMaxPerRoute` and `MaxTotal` as 100.

**Advantage:** When only one job is running, I can make full utilization of the external service.

The problem is when 10 jobs are running, 1000 threads will be competing to call the service. Is creating the default 100 threads per job be fine or would the resource contention lead to problems?

**UPDATE:**

Learnt that the client I will be using must not have a connection request timeout to checkout/lease a connection from the pool else it would throw a `ConnectionPoolTimeoutException`.

Comment: I dont understand how did you came up with 1000 threads at any point. Connection is not a thread. If you have 100 connections per route then you willl be able to write to 100 different sockets at the given time. If sync api is used then the "handling thread is simply the calling thread".

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes, in this case there will be 100 connections pooled but 1000 threads could compete for connection. The threads are created as part of the job/application start-up whereas the connections are static

Comment: And that can be perfectly fine if by design task doesn not have to have access to X shared resoure units at once in order to finish. That means tha it will work as long as job does not have to own all N connections at given time but can pool them one by one and continue its work even with 1 available connection(but pooled N times)

Answer (score 0):

I think PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager only as pool contain connections because It's only one thread. And thread for connect to url in your code control that ex:

```
public String doPost(HttpPost postMethod, ProfilerLog profilerLog, LogBuilder logBuilder)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            // execute thread
            ConnectorThread thread = new ConnectorThread(postMethod, httpClient, "Connector Thread",
                    profilerLog, logBuilder);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            thread.start();

            // tunnel response
            thread.join();
            return thread.getRespData();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
            return null;
        } finally {
            shutdown();
        }
    }
```

ConnectorThread execute target url.

Regards.